# How can I get autocomplete to work (with a keyboard shortcut) with Sequel Pro?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sequel-pro

If I type in a table name or part of a table name and wait a few seconds, a popup box will show up and allow me to choose a table or column. Is there a way to get this box to pop up without waiting - a keyboard shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The <kbd>esc</kbd> key will trigger autocomplete.